# Wordpress Woocommerce Product attribute return key not value

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, attributes

I'm trying to get products attribute of size in woocommerce
 and here's my code :

```
<?php
    $test = $_product->get_attributes();

    if ( $test != NULL ) {
        foreach($test['pa_size']['options'] as $size){
                if ($size !== NULL) {
                    echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_size',  $size , $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

                }   else  {
                    echo "Not Specified";
                }
        }
        } else {
        echo "Not Specified";
        }
?>
```

and here if the product has attributes it will check if has attribute of size. 
then It will return this size in the var $size 
the problem that I got the result not as the value of the attribute. 
the value is ( small , medium or large ) 
but I got a key value  like this.

```
48
```

So how can I get the value of the attribute not the key.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well  I found the solve here 
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/

and here's the code :

```
$test = $_product->get_attributes();
if(!empty($test)) {
    $terms = get_the_terms($product_id, "pa_size");
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    echo "<option>" . $term->name . "</option>";
    }
} else {
    echo "Not Specified";
}
```