# Show specific item attribute in WooCommerce cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have code which (I modified and took from here [Woocommerce get specific attribute value on cart page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45483525/woocommerce-get-specific-attribute-value-on-cart-page)) is showing full list of containing attributes, but I would like to use only specific attribute, let's say "colour1" to generate SVG file.

```
    <?php
    
$item_data = $cart_item['data'];
$attributes = $item_data->get_attributes();

    foreach ( $attributes as $attribute ) 
    {      
            $out ='';
            $out .= $attribute['name'] . ': ';
            $out .= $attribute['value'] . '<br />';
            echo $out;
    }
    ?>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

just found solution:

```
<?php

$item_data = $cart_item['data'];
$attributes = $item_data->get_attributes();

    foreach ( $attributes as $attribute ) 
    {      
        if ( $attribute['name'] == 'colour1' ) {
            $out ='';
            $out .= $attribute['name'] . ': ';
            $out .= $attribute['value'] . '<br />';
            echo $out;
    }
    }
    ?>
```